Invalid XML when trying to update the page contents of OneNote via VBA
I'm getting the "invalid XML" error when I try to update the contents of a newly created Page in OneNote via VBA. My XML is simple and it passes the online validators so I'm out of ideas.
XML string:
<one:Page xmlns:one="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2013/onenote" ID="SOME ID">
    <one:Title>
        <one:Text>Updated Page with Complex Content</one:Text>
    </one:Title>
    <one:Outline>
        <one:OEChildren>
            <one:OE>
                <one:Text>
                    <one:ParagraphStyle>Body</one:ParagraphStyle>
                    <one:Text>Dummy Text</one:Text>
                </one:Text>
            </one:OE>
        </one:OEChildren>
    </one:Outline>
</one:Page>


The simple answer is that this is a misinterpretation of the error messages
' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/onenote/error-codes-onenote
' 0x80042000    The XML is not well-formed.
' 0x80042001    The XML is invalid.
The XML is not well formed means there is a syntax error in the definition of the XML such as a missing "<"
The XML is invalid means that the XML is invalid with respect to the XML vocabulary that is defined by the XSD for the namespace -
in this case "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2013/onenote"
Note that if you are using Notepad++ with the XML Plugin the XML needs to be linearised
or the routine "OneNote.UpdatePageContent" gives a "not well formed" error because there
are extra CR and LF characters in the file to make it human readable.
Here is the XML for a blank page in OneNote -
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<one:Page xmlns:one="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2013/onenote"
          ID="{00}"
          name="Blank page 0857-01"
          dateTime="2024-10-15T07:57:51.000Z"
          lastModifiedTime="2024-10-15T08:44:27.000Z"
          pageLevel="1"
          isCurrentlyViewed="true">
    <one:QuickStyleDef index="0"
                       name="PageTitle"
                       fontColor="automatic"
                       highlightColor="automatic"
                       font="Calibri Light"
                       fontSize="20.0"
                       spaceBefore="0.0"
                       spaceAfter="0.0"/>
    <one:PageSettings RTL="false"
                      color="automatic">
        <one:PageSize>
            <one:Automatic/>
        </one:PageSize>
        <one:RuleLines visible="false"/>
    </one:PageSettings>
    <one:Title lang="en-GB">
        <one:OE author="David Tallett"
                authorInitials="DT"
                lastModifiedBy="David Tallett"
                lastModifiedByInitials="DT"
                creationTime="2024-10-15T08:04:39.000Z"
                lastModifiedTime="2024-10-15T08:44:20.000Z"
                objectID="{5C75DD49-BD75-49BB-96D6-F81794548E33}{15}{B0}"
                alignment="left"
                quickStyleIndex="0">
            <one:T><![CDATA[Blank page 0857-01]]></one:T>
        </one:OE>
    </one:Title>
</one:Page>

As you can see the vocabulary is not simple. This text is "Pretty print - indent attributes" using Notepad ++ with the XML Tools plugin.
This text will not load correctly and must be linearised to load.
Here is the code used to load this page.
Option Explicit

Sub sbUpdatePageXML()
    Dim OneNote As New OneNote.Application
    Dim sPageXML As String
    Dim sPageID As String
    ' replace the ID in each .XML file with {00} so that it can be replaced with the actual ID of the page
'    sPageXML = fnRead2("C:\Users\david\Desktop\SOME ID.xml")
    sPageXML = fnRead2("C:\Users\david\Desktop\OneNote - Blank page 0857-01.xml")
'   make sure the page name below is unique
    sPageID = fnGetPageID("Page2")
    MsgBox sPageID
    If sPageID = "" Then
        MsgBox "page not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    sPageXML = Replace(sPageXML, "{00}", sPageID)
    MsgBox sPageXML
    OneNote.UpdatePageContent sPageXML, , xs2013, False
End Sub

' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/onenote/error-codes-onenote
' 0x80042000    The XML is not well-formed.
' 0x80042001    The XML is invalid.
' the XML needed to be linearised!!!

Public Function fnRead2(sFile As String) As String
 Dim sText As String
 Dim i As Integer
 Open sFile For Input As #1
 sText = ""
 For i = 1 To 1000
    If Not EOF(1) Then sText = sText & Input(1, #1)
 Next i
 Close #1
 fnRead2 = sText
End Function

Function fnGetPageID(sPageName As String) As String
    Dim OneNote As New OneNote.Application
    Dim sPagesXML As String
    OneNote.GetHierarchy "", hsPages, sPagesXML, xs2013
    Dim xDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xDoc.LoadXML (sPagesXML)
    Dim nodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    xDoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:one='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2013/onenote'" ' set this property before using SelectNodes
    Set nodes = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//one:Page")

    For Each node In nodes
        If sPageName = node.Attributes.getNamedItem("name").Text Then
            fnGetPageID = node.Attributes.getNamedItem("ID").Text
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    
    ' if the name given for the page does not exist, return the first page found
    Dim node0 As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Set node0 = nodes(0)
    fnGetPageID = node0.Attributes.getNamedItem("ID").Text
End Function

Use the following VBA snippet to see the XML for all the pages in your OneNote Notebook.
Option Explicit

Sub sbGetPagesXML()
    Dim OneNote As New OneNote.Application
    Dim sPagesXML As String
    OneNote.GetHierarchy "", hsPages, sPagesXML, xs2013
    MsgBox sPagesXML
    sbPrint (sPagesXML)
End Sub

Sub sbPrint(sText As String): Open "C:\tmp\z-" & Format(Now(), "HHMMSS") & ".txt" For Output As #1: Print #1, sText: Close #1: End Sub

Software versions
Notepad ++ v8.7 (64-bit)
XML Tools Plugin version 3.1.1.13 unicode 64 bit
Microsoft® OneNote® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2409 Build 16.0.18025.20160) 64-bit
Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2409 Build 16.0.18025.20160) 64-bit
Edition
Windows 11 Home Version 23H2 OS build 22631.4317
